# Keep bootstrap input fields in line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am struggling with his problem, I have 4 input fields which should appear in a single line. Each field also has a label and the text length of this label can vary.

Simplified version of my problem

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <label>text</label> 
            <input class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <label>text</label> 
            <input class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <label>text</label> 
            <input class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <label>text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text</label> 
       <input class="form-control">
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ue7bn8qd/4/)**  (you probably have to resize the width of the output, otherwise bootstrap will show it vertically)

As you can see here the last input field is not in line with the other ones because the text of the label takes 2 lines. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: This should help you http://brm.io/jquery-match-height/

Comment: You need to set some height for `label`

Comment: @Shahil I'm not looking for a plugin, but thank you

Comment: @GokulPP this is not a static site, so I'm not sure how much text there will be. Setting a height for `label` also could have bad influence for the view on mobile devices

Comment: @PrototypeX7 you could set the height of the label inside a media query so it only applies when the page is larger than a certain width

Answer (score 0):

You need `form-group` inside `col-md-12` container

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

`col-xs-12` is optional.https://jsfiddle.net/vladavip88/qfdbg022/

Comment: This don't fix my problem. I probably wasn't clear enough. In my example above everything is working fine for me except the view for desktop devices. The last input field is not in the same line as the other 3 are, because there is to much text.

Answer (score 0):

Set the label height in a media query;

```
@media(min-width:992px){ /* default bootstrap md width */
  label {
    min-height:70px; /* adjust as appropriate */
  }
}
```

The example above will give label elements a height of 70px when the page's width is >= 992px

https://jsfiddle.net/ue7bn8qd/12/

Answer (score 0):

There are Two css properties in form-control class.

1. display: block;
2. width: 100%;

due to these properties input fields are behaving like block. That's why they are not inline. Edit these 2 properties to get your input fields inline.